# PHP Change Array Keys To Chars

Tags: php, arrays, key

I need to change the key of the arrays to chars, something like '_1' o 'a'. Example:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [val1] => GFA
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [val1] => SDF
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [val1] => ASD
        )
)
```

and I need to set like:

```
Array
(
    [_1] => Array
        (
            [val1] => GFA
        )
    [_2] => Array
        (
            [val1] => SDF
        )
    [_3] => Array
        (
            [val1] => ASD
        )
)
```

Is there any way to do that easy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about a loop along all elements in your array. Add a new element to it and remove the current element at that time.

```
foreach($yourArray as $key => $value) {
    $yourArray['_' . $key] = $value;
    unset($yourArray[$key]);
}
```

foreach should consider only the array-elements present at the start of this loop. Elements added in this loop should not influence the count of loop

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one-liner you can do:

```
$array = array_combine(array_map(function ($v) { return "_".$v; }, array_keys($array)),array_values($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

About your problem, my approch will be like this ->

```
function ChangeArrayKey($arr = array()){
   $ret = array();
   foreach($arr as $key => $value ) {
      $ret['_'.$key] = $value;
   }

   return $ret;
}

// this is how you will use this function
ChangeArrayKey($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get it like this,

```
$array = array();
foreach($yourArray as $key => $val)
{
    $array["_".$key] = $val; 
}
```

Print your array with `$array` and you will get your output.